# How to abstract Robotium Setup to run multiple test files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, robotium

In a Blackbox test environment I would need to include **CODE 1** and end with **CODE 2** to perform a test by running Android JUnit Test (as explained from the Robotium site):

**CODE 1:**

```
public class ConnectApp extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME="com.example.android.notepad.NotesList";
private static Class<?> launcherActivityClass;
private Solo solo;
static { 
    try { launcherActivityClass=Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME); }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}
public ConnectApp() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    super(launcherActivityClass);
}
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}
```

**CODE 2:**

```
public void testNumberOne() { … }
public void testNumberTwo() { … }

}
```

However, I would like to abstract **CODE 1** of the code ( which includes getInstrumentation() and getAcitvity()) so that I can simply call them in a separate test file and then run **CODE 2** . This is because I want to have tests in separate files and don't want to keep adding the same amount of **CODE 1** code but just call a method/constructor to initiate the process.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

yes there is a way to do this. What you will need to do is create an empty test class such as:

```
public class TestTemplate extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME="com.example.android.notepad.NotesList";
    private static Class<?> launcherActivityClass;
    private Solo solo;

    static { 
        try { launcherActivityClass=Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME); }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
    }
    public ConnectApp() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(launcherActivityClass);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();//I added this line in, you need it otherwise things might go wrong
        this.solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public Solo getSolo(){
        return solo;
    }
}
```

Then for every test class you want in the future instead of extending ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 you will extend TestTemplate.

for example:

```
public class ActualTest extends TestTemplate {
    public ActualTest() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    super();
}

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        //anything specific to setting up for this test
    }

    public void testNumberOne() { … }
    public void testNumberTwo() { … }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to change the 'connectApp()' constructor to 'TestTemplate()'? If not, I get the error of 'Implicit super constructor ActivitiyInstrumentationTestCase2 is undefined ...', However if I do what I said, then extending TestTemplate in my tests gives me 'Default constructor cannot handle exception type ClassNotFoundException'. What should I do, Sorry I am new to this, and once again thank you in advanced

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully this solves your issue! if it doesn't let me know what the issue is.